# Get most similar rows and order them by similarity - performance improvement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance, query-performance

I have `items` table with structure similar to this:

```
id
user_id
feature_1 
feature_2
feature_3
...
feature_20
```

Most of `feature...` fields are numbers, 3-4 of them contain text.

Now I need to find for given item items that are the most similar (have exact same fields with some weight) and order them by similarity.

I can do something like this:

```
select (IF (feature_1 = 'xxx1', 100, 0) +  
        IF (feature_2 = 'xxx2', 100, 0) + 
        IF (feature_3 = 'xxx3', 100, 0) + 
        IF (feature_4 = 'xxx4', 1, 0) + 
        ...  + 
        IF (feature_20 = 'xxx20', 1, 0)) 
        AS score, id from `items` where `id` <> 'yyy' 
        group by `id` having `score` > '0' order by `score` desc;
```

In place of `xxx` of course I put valid value of this field for item I want to compare and in place of `yyy` I put id of item I compare (I don't want include it in result). For each field I can specify the weight I want to use for similarity (here for first three 100 and for the rest 1)

Exact same technique was used in [Getting most similar rows in MySQL table and order them by similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632113/getting-most-similar-rows-in-mysql-table-and-order-them-by-similarity)

Now comes the performance. I've generated table with about 100000 items. Finding similar items for one item takes about `0.4 second`. Even if I could lower the number of feature_ fields that I need to include in comparison (and I probably won't be allowed to do this) it will take about `0.16-0.2 second` for such set.

And now it will be even worse. I need to find similar items for all items that belong to one user. Let's assume user has 100 items. I need to take them all from DB, run 100 queries like this above, then sort everything by score and remove duplicates (in PHP but it's not a problem) and then again take the whole records to display (of course final result will be paginated).

So:

- I will need to run more than 100 queries to achieve that ( I don't know if it's possible to run such query without explicit putting values in `xxx` places)
- it will take 100 x 0,4 seconds = 40 seconds to achieve that

**Questions:**

- is it possible to improve above query (use indexes or rebuild it) to make it run much faster
- is it possible to rebuild the query to get similar items not for one item but for many items (all items of one user)

I need to also add, that not all items have all `feature` fields filled (they are `nullable`) so if I look for similar items for item that have for example feature_15 field `null` I don't want to include this `feature_15` field to `score` at all because it's unknown for this item.

**EDIT**

I've created the structure as suggested by **@pala** (DB structure below). Now I have 25 records in `features` table and `2138959` (yes, over 2 millions) records in `feature_watch` table.

When I run example query:

```
select if2.watch_id, sum(f.weight) AS `sum` from feature_watch if1 
    inner join feature_watch if2 on if1.feature_id = if2.feature_id 
      and if1.feature_value = if2.feature_value 
      and if1.watch_id <> if2.watch_id 
     inner join features f on if2.feature_id = f.id 
     where if1.watch_id = 71 group by if2.watch_id ORDER BY sum DESC
```

it now takes between `1-2 seconds` to get the same result. Did I miss something here?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `features` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `weight` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_watch` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `feature_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `watch_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `feature_value` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2142999 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `features`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `features_name_unique` (`name`), ADD KEY `weight` (`weight`);

ALTER TABLE `feature_watch`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `feature_watch_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`), ADD KEY `feature_id` (`feature_id`,`feature_value`), ADD KEY `watch_id` (`watch_id`);

ALTER TABLE `features`
MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=26;

ALTER TABLE `feature_watch`
MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2142999;

ALTER TABLE `feature_watch`
ADD CONSTRAINT `feature_watch_feature_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`feature_id`) REFERENCES `features` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `feature_watch_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `feature_watch_watch_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`watch_id`) REFERENCES `watches` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**EDIT2**

For the followin query:

```
select if2.watch_id, sum(f.weight) AS `sum` from feature_watch if1 inner join feature_watch if2 on if1.feature_id = if2.feature_id and if1.feature_value = if2.feature_value and if1.watch_id <> if2.watch_id inner join features f on if2.feature_id = f.id where if1.watch_id = 71 AND if2.`user_id` in (select `id` from `users` where `is_private` = '0') and if2.`user_id` <> '1' group by if2.watch_id ORDER BY sum DESC
```

`EXPLAIN` gives:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  if1     ref     watch_id,compound,feature_id    watch_id    4   const   22  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  f   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   watches10.if1.feature_id    1   NULL
1   SIMPLE  if2     ref     watch_id,compound,feature_id,user_id    compound    457     watches10.if1.feature_id,watches10.if1.feature_val...   441     Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  users   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   watches10.if2.user_id   1   Using where
```

The above query executes over `0.5s` and if I would like to run it for more than record id 71 (put for example 10 records ids) it will execute about x times slower (about 5 seconds for 10 ids)

Comment: i dont suppose 'fix the table design' is an option?

Comment: @pala_ If it will be solution I could consider it but just in case those `feature` fields don't hold any values connected to each other for example feature_1 will hold colors and feature_2 can hold size and exact names of those `feature_` fields are different (for example color, size etc).

Comment: I really think its a good idea

Comment: I think @pala_ is on to something!!

Comment: Let's focus on the original `items` table to start with. Is `id` field unique? Please add more details about "user has 100 items". How do you determine what items user has? Just by `user_id`? When you process all items of a user, do you use the same set of feature values and weights for all items (xxx1, xxx2, ..., xxx20) OR each item has its own set of features and weights for comparison? I think it is possible to make one query instead of 100. A simplified sample data with 5 features, 10 items, 2 users AND expected result would really help.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov In items `id` is of course inique autoincremental, user_id is the only way to determine if item belongs to user, for some of features (let's say xxx1-xxx16) each value is integer that is representing real value of the feature (for example red is 336, yellow 678 etc), but some of them (lets say xxx17-xxx20) are user input values. Each item has the same feature set (xxx1-xxx20) but not all of them are required (some of them may be set to null or empty string)

Comment: Sample data would answer this question: let user has two items (yyy, zzz). When you search for items similar to item `yyy` you compare features with some values: f1=336, f2=678, f3=987 with some weights 100, 100, 1. When you search for items similar to item `zzz` do you compare features with the same set of values (336, 678, 987) OR you compare with some other set of values. Is this set of feature values the same/constant for all items of the user or not?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Each item have most features from set ranges, for example f1=1..10, f2.=21..25,f3=30..50 but 3-4 of them are from user input. So item x can have f1=1,f2=22,f3=30, item y can have f1=1,f2=21,f3=40 and item z can have f1=10,f2=25,f3=50

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you reorganise your table structure similar to the following:

```
create table items (id integer primary key auto_increment);

create table features (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  feature_name varchar(25),
  feature_weight integer
);

create table item_features (  
  item_id integer,
  feature_id integer,  
  feature_value varchar(25)
);
```

This would allow you to run a relatively simple query to calculate similarity based on features, by summing their weight.

```
select if2.item_id, sum(f.feature_weight)
  from item_features if1
    inner join item_features if2
      on if1.feature_id = if2.feature_id
        and if1.feature_value = if2.feature_value
        and if1.item_id <> if2.item_id
    inner join features f
      on if2.feature_id = f.id
   where if1.item_id = 1
   group by if2.item_id
```

There is a demo of this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/613970/4

I know it doesn't match the table definition in the question - but repeated values like that in a table are a path to the dark side. Normalisation really does make life easier.

With an index on `item_features(feature_id, feature_value)`, and also on `features(feature_name)`, the query should be quite fast

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tested your solution but it takes for my database even more time (1-2 seconds). Please look at edit in my question. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Did you create the necessary indexes?

Comment: Rather yes, I've included all of them in the edit of my question above. It seems the problem is with group by - without it the query takes almost no time, but after adding `group by if2.watch_id` (there is an index on `watch_id`) the execution time increases with over 1 second

Comment: add item_id to your compound index, that could help. how many rows are we dealing with?

Comment: I've just added, it made it faster about `0.3 s`. As I wrote in my edited question there are over 2 mln rows in the table at the moment. I also needed to add `user_id` to item_featueres table and condition `AND if2.`user_id` in (select `id` from `users` where `is_private` = '0') and if2.`user_id` <> '1'` condition to make it the same as mine and now it takes `0,5s` (now I have one index on feature_id, feature_value, watch_id (in your it's item_id) and user_id) so it's still not fast enough

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek can you post your `explain` output for the query, now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76709/discussion-between-marcin-nabialek-and-pala).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of what you want. Please tell me if I guessed it correctly or not. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38ff4/3/0)

There are many items that belong to several users as determined by `user_id`. In this example we have 3 users:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
id int, 
`user_id` int, `f1` int, `f2` int, `f3` int,
primary key(id),
key(user_id));

INSERT INTO items
    (id, `user_id`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 22, 30),
    (2, 1, 1, 21, 40),
    (3, 1, 9, 25, 50),
    (4, 2, 1, 21, 30),
    (5, 2, 1, 22, 40),
    (6, 2, 2, 22, 35),
    (7, 3, 9, 22, 31),
    (8, 3, 8, 20, 55),
    (9, 3, 7, 20, 55),
    (10, 3, 5, 26, 30)
;
```

`user_id` is a parameter of the query. For a given `user_id` you want to find all items that belong to this user, then for each found item you want to calculate the score that defines a "distance" between this item and every other item (not just from this user, but each and every other item). And then you want to show all rows of the result ordered by the score. Not just the single most similar item, but all of them.

The score of a pair of items is calculated using values of features of these two items. There is no constant set of feature values that is compared to all items, each pair of items may have its own score.

When the score is calculated each feature has a weight. These weights are predefined and constant (do not depend on the item). Let's use these constants in this example:

```
weight for f1 is 1
weight for f2 is 3
weight for f3 is 5
```

Here is one way to get the result in one query (for `user_id=1`):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      UserItems.id AS UserItemID
      ,AllItems.id AS AllItemID
      ,IF(AllItems.f1 = UserItems.f1, 1, 0)+
      IF(AllItems.f2 = UserItems.f2, 3, 0)+
      IF(AllItems.f3 = UserItems.f3, 5, 0) AS Score
    FROM
      (
        SELECT id, f1, f2, f3
        FROM items
        WHERE items.user_id = 1
      ) AS UserItems
      CROSS JOIN
      (
        SELECT id, f1, f2, f3
        FROM items
      ) AS AllItems
  ) AS Scores
WHERE
  UserItemID <> AllItemID
  AND Score > 0
ORDER BY UserItemID, Score desc
```

**Result set**

```
| UserItemID | AllItemID | Score |
|------------|-----------|-------|
|          1 |        10 |     5 |
|          1 |         4 |     5 |
|          1 |         6 |     4 |
|          1 |         5 |     3 |
|          1 |         7 |     3 |
|          2 |         5 |     6 |
|          2 |         4 |     4 |
|          3 |         7 |     1 |
```

If this is really what you want, I'm afraid there is no magic way to make it work fast. For each item of the user you need to compare it to each other item to calculate the score. So, if there are `N` rows in the `items` table and `M` items for a given user you have to calculate the score `N*M` times. Then you have to filter out zero scores and sort the result. You can't avoid reading the whole `items` table `M` times.

Only if there is some external knowledge about the data, then maybe you could "cheat" somehow and read not the whole `items` table every time.

For example, if you know that distribution of values of feature K is very uneven: 99% of values are X and 1% are some other values. It may be possible to make use of this knowledge to reduce amount of calculations.

Another example, if items cluster somehow together (in the sense of your metric/distance/score). If you can pre-calculate these clusters, then instead of reading through the whole table of items every time you could read only small subset of those items that belong to the same cluster using appropriate indexes.